# Uniqueness of the argument $\theta$ in the Polar representation of a complex number.

Tags: complex-analysis

I was reading this,

[image]
Here, $r$ and $\theta$ is defined by $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and $\cos\theta=\frac{x}{r}$, $\sin\theta=\frac{y}{r}$ for some complex number $z=(x,y)$.

My question is since we have two different angles in $(-\pi, \pi]$ for Cosine and Sine for every value between $-1$ and $1$, then why is $\theta$ unique in the polar representation if $-\pi<\theta\le\pi$.

Thanks!

Comment: Take two distinct angles $\theta$ and $\theta'$ for which $\cos \theta = \cos \theta'$. Then $\sin \theta = -\sin \theta'$. In other words, yes, cosine and sine have repeated values, but taken as a pair, $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ will be unique.

Comment: @Théophile, I can see your point while I look at the graphs. Is there a way to prove if $\cos\theta=\cos\theta^{'}$ then, $\sin\theta=-\sin\theta^{'}$ in this interval?

Comment: In particular, that happens when $\theta' = -\theta$; then use evenness of $\cos$ and oddness of $\sin$. Alternatively, taking $r=1$ for simplicity, consider that $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ is really just $(x,y)$: if you take some point on the circle, there will be a mirror image below it. The $x$ value is the same, but the $y$ value has the opposite sign.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The point being made is not about the injectivity of $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$.

Yes, in an interval $I$ of length $2\pi$, these functions are not necessarily injective. But that's not the point.

The sum, $\cos \theta + i \sin \theta \equiv e^{i\theta}$, **will** be injective on that interval. For $\theta$ in that interval, a whole unit circle will be traced. You need each value in such an $I$ to get a distinct angle on that unit circle.

Playing with $t_0$ in [this Desmos demo](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lmygoj5snh) might prove instructive. Notice how it repeats every $2\pi$. So if $t_0 = 1$, it won't reach that same value until we hit $t_0 = 1+2\pi$, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the demo! It's pretty clear to me now!